# To what extent is Rust shadowing zero-cost?

Tags: rust, shadowing

[A Zero-Runtime-Cost Mixed List in Rust](http://nercury.github.io/rust/interesting/2015/12/12/typed-arrays.html) outlines how to create a heterogenous list in Rust using tuples and normal traits (not trait objects like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27957103/how-do-i-create-a-heterogeneous-collection-of-objects) suggests). The list seems to rely heavily on shadowing and effectively changes the entire type of the list every time a new element is added.

The implementation seems brilliant to me, but after reviewing a few Rust's homepage and resources I could not find anyplace that explicitly defines shadowing as zero-cost. As far as I know, repeatedly abandoning data on the stack is less costly than indirection, but repeatedly copying and adding to existing data instead of mutating it sounds pretty expensive.

> What you don’t use, you don’t pay for. And further: What you do use, you couldn’t hand code any better.
>
> - Bjarne Stroustrup

Shadowing seems to fulfill the first requirement, but the second?

Is Rust's shadowing actually zero-cost?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Official Rust material tries very hard to never talk about "zero cost" by itself, so you'll have to cite where you see "zero cost" without further qualification. [The article](http://nercury.github.io/rust/interesting/2015/12/12/typed-arrays.html) states zero **runtime** cost, so the author of the post is aware of that. In most cases, "zero cost" is used in the context of *zero-cost abstractions*.

Your Stroustrup quote only partially and obliquely deals with zero-cost abstractions. A better explanation, emphasis mine:

> It means paying no penalty **for the abstraction**, or said otherwise, it means that whether you use the abstraction or instead go for the "manual" implementation you end up having the same costs (same speed, same memory consumption, ...).
>
> - [Matthieu M.](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/5lg3ih/what_do_rusts_buzzwords_like_safe_and_zerocost/dbvfkyv?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x)

This means that any time you see "zero-cost abstraction", you have to have *something to compare the abstraction against*; only then can you tell if it's truly zero-cost.

I don't think that shadowing even counts as an *abstraction*, but let's pretend it does (and I'll word the rest of my answer as if I believe it is).

Shadowing a variable means having multiple distinct variables with the same name, with the later ones precluding access to the previous ones. The non-"abstract" version of that is having multiple distinct variables of different names. I'd say that having two variables of the same name **is the same cost** as having two variables of different names, so it is a zero-cost abstraction.

See also:

- [Why do I need rebinding/shadowing when I can have mutable variable binding?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40621325/155423)
- [In Rust, what's the difference between "shadowing" and "mutability"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53235334/155423)

---

Playing the game further, you can ask "is having two variables a zero-cost abstraction?". I'd say that this depends on what the variables are and how they relate.

In this example, I'd say that this is a zero-cost abstraction as there's no more efficient way I could have written the code.

```
fn example() {
    let a = String::new();
    let a = a;
}
```

On the other hand, I'd say that this is not a zero-cost abstraction, as the first `a` will not be deallocated until the end of the function:

```
fn example() {
    let a = String::new();
    let a = String::new();
}
```

A better way I could choose to write it would be to call `drop` in the middle. There are good reasons that Rust doesn't do this, but it's not *as* efficient in regards to memory usage as a hand-written implementation could be.

See also:

- [Is it possible in Rust to delete an object before the end of scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42910662/155423)
- [Does Rust free up the memory of overwritten variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48227347/155423)
- [Is the resource of a shadowed variable binding freed immediately?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30304145/155423)